# How to set up compute_metric function for Donut Transformer using trainer?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

[This image is what I got from the trainer.train()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLR6B.png)I am trying to fine-tune a Donut Transformer using trainer(). And I am wondering what kind of compute_metric function should I use?

Here is what I tried.

```
def compute_metrics(pred):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
    precision, recall, f1, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(labels, preds, average='binary')
    acc = accuracy_score(labels, preds)
    return {
        'accuracy': acc,
        'f1': f1,
        'precision': precision,
        'recall': recall
    }
```

But it is not returning other metrics accuracy, f1, etc.